# How to submit after getting the value from select box option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner with Javascript.

I have written code for getting the values from selected option and it works fine.

My question is after selecting all the three options, if I click on "submit"
button it should go to the next page.

can someone please help on this?

**Condition to be executed while redirecting to another page:**

```
if(strUser == 'AAA') && (strUser1 == 'DDD') && (strUser1 == 'GGG'))
    {
        window.location.replace("sample4.html");
    }
    else if(strUser == 'BBB') && (strUser1 == 'EEE') && (strUser1 == 'HHH'))
    {
        window.location.replace("sample5.html");
    }
    else
        {
        alert("please select all the 3 options");
        }
}
```

Code:

```
<body
    style="background-image: url(./img/ford3.png); background-size: cover;">
    <h3>welcome user!!</h3>
    <button class="ssystem">System</button>
    <button class="sub">Sub-System</button>
    <button class="subsub">Sub-Sub-System</button>

    <div class="box">
        <select name="select1" id="sys" onchange="showData();">
            <option value="1">AAA</option>
            <option value="2">BBB</option>
            <option value="3">CCC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
        <select id="sub" onchange="showData();">
            <option value="4">DDD</option>
            <option value="5">EEE</option>
            <option value="6">FFF</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <select id="sub1" onchange="showData();">
            <option value="7">GGG</option>
            <option value="8">HHH</option>
            <option value="9">III</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
    <script>
    function showData() {
       var e = document.getElementById("sys");
    var e1 = document.getElementById("sub");
    var e2 = document.getElementById("sub1");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(strUser);
    //var value = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value; //for index
    //alert(value);
    var strUser1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(strUser1);
    var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(strUser2);

     </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

There were a few things wrong with your code.

Firstly, you want to make your state variables (values that can change) of a higher scope so you can share them between your functions. These are the values of your `<select>` html elements.

Since all your default values are at index zero, we can just default to that selected index value upon initialisation of the page.

We can extract the `<select>` DOM element into a variable with `document.getElementById()` and then get the selected option value out of it like so:

`var strUser = document.getElementById("sys").options[0].text;`.

Another thing is that your IF statements were incorrectly written. I amended this for example here:

`if (strUser == 'AAA' && strUser1 == 'DDD' && strUser2 == 'GGG')`

I left the alerts in there so you can see the sequential flow of the code.

Additionally, I moved the Javascript to a separate file and imported it through the `<script>` tag. This is a nice separation of concerns.

A link to a JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ShaneCreedon/5ucnj3q7/) for a more visual effect of how the code works.

I hope this helps.

**HTML**

```html
<body
    style="background-image: url(./img/ford3.png); background-size: cover;">
    <h3>welcome user!!</h3>
    <button class="ssystem">System</button>
    <button class="sub">Sub-System</button>
    <button class="subsub">Sub-Sub-System</button>

    <div class="box">
        <select name="select1" id="sys" onchange="showData();">
            <option value="1">AAA</option>
            <option value="2">BBB</option>
            <option value="3">CCC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box1">
        <select id="sub" onchange="showData();">
            <option value="4">DDD</option>
            <option value="5">EEE</option>
            <option value="6">FFF</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <select id="sub1" onchange="showData()">
            <option value="7">GGG</option>
            <option value="8">HHH</option>
            <option value="9">III</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button" onclick="goToNextPage()">
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```js
var strUser = document.getElementById("sys").options[0].text;
var strUser1 = document.getElementById("sub").options[0].text;
var strUser2 = document.getElementById("sub1").options[0].text;

function showData() {
  var e = document.getElementById("sys");
  var e1 = document.getElementById("sub");
  var e2 = document.getElementById("sub1");

  strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  alert(strUser);

  strUser1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text;
  alert(strUser1);

  strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
  alert(strUser2);
}

function goToNextPage() {
  if (strUser == 'AAA' && strUser1 == 'DDD' && strUser2 == 'GGG') {
    window.location.replace("sample4.html");
  }
  else if (strUser == 'BBB' && strUser1 == 'EEE' && strUser2 == 'HHH') {
    window.location.replace("sample5.html");
  }
  else {
    alert("please select all the 3 options");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked..thank you so much for the knowledge and help..